# How can I create a web form automatically when an organic group is created?

Tags: 6, organic-groups, webforms

I would like to automatically create a webform when a new organic group node is created.

The webform should have predefined fields and trigger an email to the group administrator or a user in the group with a predetermined role.  Alternatively it could email an address filled out in a cck field on the group content type.

I tried using og_webform but couldn't figure out how to get it to create webforms for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably multiple was to this.  The way I see it is a custom module.

You want to use hook_nodeapi(&$node, $op) in Drupal 6,  hook_node_insert($node) in Drupal 7.

You code would look like something like this

```
CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME_nodeapi(&node, $op) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'insert':
       if ($node->type == 'group') {
         global $user;

         // Create new object.
         $node = new stdClass();

         // Set desired data and metadata as members in object.
         $node->type = 'predefine_webform_with_predefine_fields';
         $node->uid = $user->uid;
         $node->title = 'node title';
         $node->body = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...';
         //... prefill other cck fields

         // Save the node
         node_save($node);

       }
       break;
     }
   }
}
```

(Code should look the same for Drupal 7, minus the switch case)

Comment: This worked, I ended up loading, and saving an existing webform node with a new uid and nid.

Answer (score 0):

To create a node programmatically , on some specific action we have to  make some changes in node.module

on line no. 874, find node_save($node)
suppose you have a situation where you want to create a node from specific content type i.e. 'page' then.
and programmatically node is

story type the code will be

```
    if($node->type=="page")
         {
    $node_new = new StdClass();
            //creating a bare node

    $node_new->type = 'story ';
    //giving it type

    $node_new->status = 1;
    //give it a published staus

    $node_new->title = "This is story title";
    //gives title

    $node_new->body = "This is story  body";
    //gives body

    node_save($node_new);

    //save it and give it the rest of the attributes    
    //drupal_set_message('Automated '.$node_new->type.'Created');
}
```

[Click Here to view original post](http://imdrupal.com/creating-node-programmatically-drupal)

Comment: You meant to hack the file ???